# parallel for loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, parfor

I am using a `parfor` in my code, I read all `parfor` limitations and I think I am doing everything right:

```
for it = 1:maxiter
    rep_it = it;
    parfor Fo = allFo
        rep_Fo = Fo;
        Fmax = 2*Fo;
        find_rep = find(rep_Fo==allFo) ;
        [Fac, c, F_est,loss] = AutoTen(info.Data,Fmax,2);
        [Fac, F_est_baseline3] = AutoTenBaseline(info.Data,Fmax,1);
        [Fac, F_est_baseline3] = AutoTenBaseline(info.Data,Fmax,2);
        est_rank(find_rep,rep_it) = F_est;
        est_rank_baseline1(find_rep,rep_it) = F_est_baseline3;
        est_rank_baseline2(find_rep,rep_it) = F_est_baseline3;
    end
end
```

But I get the error:

> Error: The variable est_rank in a parfor cannot be classified

Any help is appreciated how to solve this.

Comment: I know that I should use a cell-array instead of est_rank, but it didn't help either.

Comment: Looks like you have a sliced variable problem: http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/sliced-variables.html

Comment: Even when I'm using something like this, i have the error: `code`parfor Fo = 4:5
        rep_Fo = Fo - 2;Fmax = 2*Fo;
est_rank{1} = F_est;
end`code`

Comment: I have read the sliced variables, but still I do not know how to solve it. Could you please give a hint? @Trogdor  I have to add find_rep always returns a single value.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from the `find_rep` and `rep_it` variables that are used for indexing. If you want `est_rank` to be sliceable, you have to use the `Fo` index for it like:

```
est_rank(Fo, rep_it) = F_est;
```

otherwise you (i.e. MATLAB) cannot guarantee that you won't try to access the same cell in the variable from two parallel processes.

If I got your intention correctly, then this fix should do it:

```
for it = 1:maxiter
    parfor Fo = 1:numel(allFo)
        Fmax = 2*allFo(Fo);
        [Fac, c, F_est,loss] = AutoTen(info.Data,Fmax,2);
        [Fac, F_est_baseline3] = AutoTenBaseline(info.Data,Fmax,1);
        [Fac, F_est_baseline3] = AutoTenBaseline(info.Data,Fmax,2);
        est_rank(Fo,it) = F_est;
        est_rank_baseline1(Fo,it) = F_est_baseline3;
        est_rank_baseline2(Fo,it) = F_est_baseline3;
    end
end
```

Let me know if it did the trick ;)

Comment: @Erin, let me know if this answers your question, and if so, please consider upvote/accepting it